# How to create a UDF that returns 2-D array

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, user-defined-functions

and plots the result in 2-D cells in Excel? 
I am using C#, .NET, Excel-DNA, Add-In Express RTD,

Thanks

Edit
I tried http://excel-dna.net/2011/01/30/resizing-excel-udf-result-arrays/, does not work for me. 
I want sth like this 
MyUDF(param1, param2) returns a 2-D array like a table based on lengths of param1, param2
say param1 is "a,b,c", param2 is "high,low", expected to return an array [3,2], and display the result in 3 rows by 2 columns

I also tried [Excel ExcelDNA C# / Try to copy Bloomberg BDH() behavior (writing Array after a web request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668649/excel-exceldna-c-sharp-try-to-copy-bloomberg-bdh-behavior-writing-array-aft),  it works fine. 
but my requirement is backgroundworker will call RTD function, the RTD function is a multi-step process, first it will login(asychronous, then subscribe(asychronous), when I call xlcall.RTD from backgroundworker, it gives accessinviolation exception

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you run into? What are "2-D cells"?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gabhan_berry/archive/2008/04/07/writing-custom-excel-worksheet-functions-in-c_2d00_sharp.aspx

Comment: I have tried http://excel-dna.net/2011/01/30/resizing-excel-udf-result-arrays/,  it returns #Value!, not working for me. see more in edit

Answer (score 1):

Excel UDF and RTD are passive things. When the user enters a formula, Excel invokes the UDF (RTD function) to calculate the formula and to put the result back to the calling cell(s). Unlike RTD, a UDF can find out where it is called from, but both of them cannot “extend” the calling range. Extending the range would also modify the formulas/values in other cells – and this is not among the things allowed for the UDF; the RTD server doesn't have access to the Excel object model at all.

Consider combining a COM add-in and RTD server in the same assembly. The COM add-in can handle the SheetChange event to determine if the user enters a formula that refers to your RTD. When this occurs, the COM add-in can fill any required range of cells with formulas or data and  also set some flag(s) or store data accessible by your RTD. Also, the RTD can call a public method defined in the add-in and it can fill any cells this way. If you choose this option, you undoubtedly will call such a method in the RefreshData event. Note however that at this moment Excel may not be prepared to COM calls that modify the cells. To avoid potential problems, I recommend modifying the cells after a delay, see ADXAddinModule.SendMessage() method and ADXAddinModule.OnSendMessage event. The point is that the OnSendMessage event occurs only when Excel finishes its tasks and when it is ready for requests.

What do you think?

Regards from Belarus (GMT+3),

Andrei Smolin
Add-in Express Team Leader

Comment: thank you, Sir. Do you have any example?  How do I make sure OnSendMessage event occurs after Excel is ready?

Comment: Thanks, Sir. I am thinking to call a public method in RefreshEvent. I will remember callers of each function in a dictionary, in refreshevent, I will look up its caller and then plot in excel.  I did not get sheetChange event part. thanks

Comment: See HowTo: Create a COM add-in, XLL UDF and RTD server in one assembly - http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2010/03/24/addin-xll-rtd-one-assembly/.

Comment: The SendMessage event occurs only when Excel is ready; you don't need to do anything else. SheetChange occurs only when you enter something; it doesn't occur when your RTD refreshes the cell(s). I suggest that you write us at the support desk (find it readme.txt).

Comment: I see this http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=4947, it says "You can safely update cells from XLL macro functions only." so I wonder how to do that under addin express context. thanks